# Git + sourcetree clone and branch create - why only one local copy?

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm just starting with git.

I've cloned main from sourcetree, got all files in the folder. Then I created a branch, then another branch, but in my local copy it' still only one copy of all the folders. But if I need locally change files in one branch but have them unchanged in another, how can I make every branch create different local copy?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. It is not clear from the question what is your expected result. You might want to paste a more detailed explanation or perhaps expected file tree of the branches. In general, [git rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase) would be an example of updating a branch to match contents of another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have a subversion (or similar) background. That's the *default* way to use git. A single *working tree* that you use to move around in the separate branches. If your background is on svn, imagine what it would be to have a single `working copy` and use `svn switch` to move around instead of creating more `working copies`. It's more or less the same... except that moving around is extremely fast because checkout operations are local. Here is probably the most important thing for your question: when you switch from one branch to the other, the files will be changed to the branch you are switching to in your working tree.

It's possible to have more than one *working tree*, through `git worktree`:

```
# add a couple of working trees
git worktree add dir1 main # create a worktree in directory dir1 that uses branch main
git worktree add dir2 dev # create a worktree in directory dir2 that uses branch dev
git worktree list # show the 3 worktrees that you now have
```

But if you are a beginner, I would advice you to use a single working tree until you get the hang of it.... unless you have a **real** need for it.